# ios app integrated with IBM trusteer upload to app store error: ITMS-90171 Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I have integrated IBM Trusteer to the ios app we have created using IBM Mobilefirst Cli 7.1 by following the turtorial : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/product-integration/7.1/trusteer-ios/

Now , I am getting error shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you using a Hybrid project or a Native iOS project? What is your exact MobileFirst Platform 7.1 build number?

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, it is complaining about *libtas_phonegap_plugin.a*. I can't say *why* it's complaining, but I can tell you you do not need this file at all. According to the tutorial you linked to, you need **libtas_full.a**, not the "phonegap" file.

See also: http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2015/03/15/invalid-bundle-structure/

You may have placed the libtas_phonegap_plugin.a file inside a folder instead of just including it it in the list of linked libraries.